# How to scale data point values of signals in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need some help scaling data in Matlab. For example, I have three signals with different number of data points, I want to scale them to have the same number of data points but keep the same pattern (peaks), how do I use it in Matlab?

Original signals:

```
a=[5,2,9,2,1,3];
b=[6,5,8,1,1];
c=[4,4,12,5,5,4,3,1];
```

Ideally, I want new signals a_new,b_new,c_new so that `10=length(a_new)=length(b_new)=length(c_new)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the signal processing or timeseries toolbox you can use the [resample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/resample.html) function.

If not, and you don't want to write your own resampling function, then you could get by using the [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/interp1.html) function.

However, with so few samples, you will have issues with interpolation errors.

Comment: Hi @user3019763, can you give me an example how to use interp1 in my case please? Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you want the arrays stretched to fit 10 points or are they sampled at a constant rate?